# Examining NKJV's and KJV's inclusion of "Saying, I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last: and," in Revelation 1:11

Tags: revelation, textual-criticism, kjv

The phrase "Saying, I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last: and," that is in the King James Bible and the New King James Version is not found in most translations of the bible.

Are the words in question in any Greek New Testament texts? If not, what is NKJV's and KJB's reason for including this phrase?

Revelation 1:11 KJB Saying, I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last: and, What thou seest, write in a book, and send it unto the seven churches which are in Asia; unto Ephesus, and unto Smyrna, and unto Pergamos, and unto Thyatira, and unto Sardis, and unto Philadelphia, and unto Laodicea.

Revelation 1:11 NKJV saying, “I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last,” and, “What you see, write in a book and send it to the seven churches which are in Asia: to Ephesus, to Smyrna, to Pergamos, to Thyatira, to Sardis, to Philadelphia, and to Laodicea.”